# How to set a time uniform in webgl

Tags: webgl

I am new to webgl. I am trying to set a time uniform, so I can change the output of my fragment shader as time passes. I thought this would be fairly simple to implement but I am struggling. I am aware that these two methods are probably involved:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLUniformLocation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/uniform

Is some kind of rendering loop required?

Any help here would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks - see my current solution below

Comment: [You might find these articles useful](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my current solution...

In my webgl JS file I create a time uniform, then set it every animation frame with an updated value.

```
// create time uniform
var timeLocation = context.getUniformLocation(program, "u_time"); 

function renderLoop(timeStamp) { 

  // set time uniform
  gl.uniform1f(timeLocation, timeStamp/1000.0);

  gl.drawArrays(...);

  // recursive invocation
  window.requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}

// start the loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
```

Then in my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform float u_time;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(sin(u_time)),0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Comment: FYI: `requestAnimationFrame` passes the time to the callback. In other words you don't need `var = performance.now()` just use `function renderLoop(now) {`

Comment: you also don't need `timeStart`. the time passed to `requestAnimationFrame` always starts at 0